# Kick "ghosts" users in Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I dont know how to manage to create a function or something that verifies when a user dont send anything to a discord server in a period of time and kick this user for being innactive. Its not like pruning users, because pruning will kick users that didnt logged in in that time.

I am using discord.py from Rapptz, but you can give me (if possible) an example in whatever wrapper that you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on rewrite, you can use the `history` async iterator to find the user's last message.

[Documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Member.history)

Example from Documentation

```
counter = 0
# Limit is not required, but can make this a really slow operation if you don't use it.
async for message in channel.history(limit=200): 
    if message.author == client.user:
        counter += 1
```

Another method would be to keep track of a timestamp of the 'last message sent' in a JSON or any other database using the `on_message()` event. Then, you can either execute a command to purge or do it every X seconds.

The latter would probably be ideal if you're not using rewrite or if the server you're using has a lot of members.

If you're using `on_message` to handle the timestamp, you can implement it like this

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    # GET user (msg.author) and edit their timestamp on database
```

Comment: I didnt want to bother you, but, im new to this API and I didnt know where I am suppose to "put" this code. If I put it in the @bot.event for each message, it shows an error. if I put this in on_ready, it shows an error too. I tried to search examples, etc, but unsucefull.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't know if you're still following this thread, but you shouldn't be putting this for on_ready event, since it'll only run at boot-time. You should be either using `on_message` event or inside some command. If you show me your code, it'll help me help you with your problem.

Comment: I create a sqlite3 database with the user_id and server_id, with the date of the last message of the user. I see all the members of a server too and if the member is not in the user datatable, I insert it with the actual date, only one time. So, after 7 days, I kick the users that dont send any message.

Comment: So you should be using on_message event. Every time a message appears, it should update the date column with a new date.

If you want to make it so at exactly 7 days, it kicks the user, you need to create an event in the event loop. I can't really help you there, you'd have to look at the asyncio library to figure out how to do that.

Otherwise, you could make a !purge command to kick everyone who's timestamp is greater than 7 days.

Comment: Do keep in mind that if you do decide to make an event for it, it can cause unintended results when you leave the bot offline for too long. I would only recommend autokicking as an event if your bot is on 99.99% of the time